# Check sets contain/match the set of a set in Dart

Tags: dart, set, contains

A sets `receipt` is a set of sets:

```
Set dish1 = {'a', 'b'};
Set dish2 = {'c', 'd'};
Set dish3 = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
Set dish4 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
Set receipt = {dish1, dish2, dish3, dish4};
```

I would like to find the logic that can test whether a `material` belongs to a certain `dish` of above `receipt`.

```
Set material1 = {'a', 'b'}; // return dish1
Set material2 = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; // dish3
Set material3 = {'a', 'b', 'd'}; // null
Set material4 = {'b', 'c', 'a'}; // dish3
```

`material3` `{'a', 'b', 'd'}` returns null not the `dish1` because I'm looking for an exact element match but the order doesn't matter so `material4` `{'b', 'c', 'a'}` can return `dish3`.

Thank you.

Comment: So your `material1` returns `dish1` because it is a better match than `dish4` because it is the most specific? Or is it just because `dish1` was inserted before `dish4` in the `receipt` set of sets?

Comment: Shouldn't `material` be called `materials`? (or more typically for the cooking/food domain, `ingredients`). In any case, this is just a matter of checking if the `ingredients` set is a subset of any of the `dish` sets in the `Receipt`. There doesn't appear to be anything like a `isSubset()` method built in, but it's pretty easy to write your own.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, `ingredients` is better. I look for something similar to that function, do you mind to share your approach?

Comment: @julemand101 yes `naterial1` returns `dish1` because it's most specific regardless its order in `receipt`. Thanks.

Comment: @Graphite A set like `ingredients` is a subset of a set like `dish1` if for every element of `ingredients` (an `ingredient`), that `ingredient` is also a member of `dish1`. Turns out Dart *does* have `isSubset()`, but it has the more general name `containsAll()`. I found that out from seeing what people did over on [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set#Dart), which can be a good reason for seeing how to do the basics like this in various languages. See https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/Set/containsAll.html

Comment: If you want to check if one set is a subset of another, do `otherSet.containsAll(firstSet)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to have `dish1`, `dish2`, etc. available for your result, they actually have to be in your program. You can do this with a [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Map-class.html).

```
void main() {
  var receipt = {
    'dish1': {'a', 'b'},
    'dish2': {'c', 'd'},
    'dish3': {'a', 'b', 'c'},
    'dish4': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
  };

  var availableIngredients = {'b', 'c', 'a'};

  var dishesWithAvailableIngredients = receipt
    .entries
    .where(
      (entry) => entry.value.containsAll(availableIngredients)
    )
    .map((entry) => entry.key);
    
  print(dishesWithAvailableIngredients);
}
```

Of course, it might be nice to have some more structured data model in place:

```dart
void main() {
  var receipt = new Receipt([
    new Dish(name: 'dish1', ingredients: {'a', 'b'}),
    new Dish(name: 'dish2', ingredients: {'c', 'd'}),
    new Dish(name: 'dish3', ingredients: {'a', 'b', 'c'}),
    new Dish(name: 'dish4', ingredients: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}),
  ]);
  print(receipt.dishesWithIngredients({'b', 'c', 'a'}));
}

class Dish {
  // Might also want to track quantity, but I'm leaving that out
  String name;
  Set<String> ingredients;

  Dish({String name, Set<String> ingredients}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
  }

  bool containsAll(Set<String> ingredients) {
    return this.ingredients.containsAll(ingredients);
  }

  String toString() {
    return "Dish(name: ${name}, ingredients: ${ingredients})";
  }
}

class Receipt {
  List<Dish> dishes;

  Receipt(List<Dish> dishes) {
    this.dishes = dishes;
  }

  Iterable<Dish> dishesWithIngredients(Set<String> ingredients) {
    return dishes.where((d) => d.containsAll(ingredients));
  }

  String toString() {
    return "Receipt(dishes: ${dishes})";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as expected. I was struggling with trying by myself while seeking a best approach. As a newbie, may I also ask questions like this, how would you suggest to research? I tried the official docs but always felt gaps to achieve.

Comment: @Graphite Depends, which part of this are you struggling with specifically?

Comment: I guess the basics such as the usage of `.where()` and `.map()`. Do you suggest to read though [the Dart official document](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#example-using-where) the best way to improve?

Comment: I end up with making a small change to be `.where((entry) => SetEquality().equals(entry.value, availableIngredients))` or `.where(entry.value.containsAll(availableIngredients) && (entry.value.length == availableIngredients.length))`to find the exact match (regardless ordering).

Comment: I’m astounded that set equality isn’t built into dart’s standard library, but yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @Graphite I mean, that documentation looks pretty promising. It’s higher level and more conceptual than mere API documentation, with some nice examples. Funny enough, this is the first program I’ve ever written  in dart. I knew the kinds of operations I was looking for, and found them by searching through the API docs for List, Map and Iterable, combined with some stackoverflow searches

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to compare sets for equality, in order to see whether one set is equal to another.
You can use `package:collection`'s [`SetEquality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/SetEquality-class.html) for that.

That would make the code to look up an set in set of sets:

```dart
Set? findDish(Set<Set> receipt, Set dish) {
  for (var receiptDish in receipt) {
    if (const SetEquality().equals(receiptDish, dish)) {
      return receiptDish;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

That's not particularly efficient. Instead you could use a custom hash map to store the receipts, and allow direct lookup by a set:

```dart
const setEquality = SetEquality();
Set<Set> receipt = HashSet<Set>(
    equals: setEquality.equals, hashCode: setEquality.hash)
  ..addAll([dish1, dish2, dish3, dish4]);
```

Then you can directly look up a set in the other set:

```dart
Set? material1 = receipt.lookup({'a', 'b'}); // return dish1
Set? material2 = receipt.lookup({'a', 'b', 'c'}); // dish3
Set? material3 = receipt.lookup({'a', 'b', 'd'}); // null
Set? material4 = receipt.lookup({'b', 'c', 'a'}); // dish3
```

Comment: Thanks but all return the sets not the name of dish (expecting `dish1` or `dish3` to be returned), is there any efficient way to achieve?

Comment: @Graphite That's a flaw in your design of your `receipt` object. Currently, `dish1`, `dish2`, etc. are just variable names *with absolutely no significance to the program at runtime*. On most programming systems, inlining constants and squashing variable names is one of the first transformations that happens during lowering. They exist solely for human convenience, as compared to dealing with raw addresses and offsets. If these strings have significance to your program, then you should use a dictionary to key your dishes by their string names.

Comment: Thank you @Irn. May I ask what would be the best practice to find/research the right function like this? I actually referenced the api documents frequently, but as a newbie, is there any direction you would suggest?

Comment: You should know the basic data structures, `List`/`Map`/`Set`, and when to use them. Then I'd recommend browsing the platform libraries and `package:collection` APIs to be somewhat familiar with them. Then start out by being *very clear* about the problem you're trying to solve. What are the inputs, what are the outputs, what what are the performance requirements? Then you can try to find a data structure which allows you to do that. Here, for example, the requirements were not very clear.

Comment: It's very kind advice, thank you Irn.